What discount rate to use for Eurodollar options?
What discounting rate should one use to discount eurodollar options?

eurodollar options were discontinued when libor ceased

thanks for replying. yes i understand, im asking more for research purposes. i have eurodollar options and want to build better model for them using historical data, hence im asking what rate one uses; the options are on ED futures so should one use futures rate? swap rate using a FF curve?
